# No files found for KieBase: XXXXRules

Tags: classpath, drools, kie

Getting the issue when I build the code as jar (spring boot app ) & run

```
WARN  o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieProject - No files found for KieBase rrrrrules
```

It works fine when run in intellij ( without bundling as jar)

```
    @Bean
    public KieContainerSessionsPool kieContainerSessionsPool()
    {
        return KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer().newKieSessionsPool(kieSessionPoolSize);
    }
```

```
    package com.site.myapp

rule "my rule 1"
    when
        // some conditions
    then
        // something to do
end
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <kbase name="rulesss" packages="com.site.myapp">
        <ksession name="rrrrrules" />
    </kbase>
```

```
        StatelessKieSession kieSession = kieContainerSessionsPool.newKieSession("rrrrrules");
kieSession.insert(object);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
.....
```

when I extract the jar I see the drl files in the location but I dont know why its not picking up

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to fire the rules in the "rulesss" kbase? Why aren't you using the "rrrrrules" ksession?

Comment: Also it's unclear what "getting the issue when I deploy in the environment boxes" means. What's "environment boxes"? and I presume "it workers file" actually means "it works fine" when run locally, but posibly I'm not understanding that either....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas when I bundle as jar ( spring boot ) and ran I got `WARN  o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieProject` - No files found for KieBase rrrrrules but when I run on intellij the rules are executing.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is that how you're building your JAR and executing it does not resemble how IntelliJ is preparing the classpath and environment and executing. You should get those aligned. Unfortunately you show not much of anything about your build process, pom, directory structure, etc.